# Animate UIImageView size that has an aspectFit

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I'm using `EXPhotoViewer` (https://github.com/Julioacarrettoni/EXPhotoViewer)
to get fullscreen images.

Works OK - but the problem is that the original UIImageView is set to `AspectFit` - so animating the frame of the UIImageView itself - causes an effect of a "jump" after the animation ends (because only then the AspectFit kicks in)

Any way I can make it smooth?

Answer (score 0):

The UIImageView in the popup window should be `AspectFit` as well - as then everything is fine...